# Wordpress Function = 0

Tags: php, wordpress, function

i'm a absolute noob with php coding and I guess after several laughs, the solution is really simple for a professional. I coded a simple average-calculation for the category.php of my wp-template and it works perfectly but I heard that it's the much better way to split design and function and so I tried to convet this to a template function:

```
<?php

$total = 0;
$count = 0;

foreach($posts as $post)
{
     if(get_field('weight')){ // If we have a value add it to the total and count it
        $total += get_field('weight');
        $count++;
     }
}

$Average = $total / $count; 
echo $Average;       
?>
```

The result is always "0" because I guess he pulls the variable from above and skips the foreach-procedure. But why?

```
function averageit()
{
$total = 0;
$count = 0;
foreach($posts as $post)
    if(get_field('weight'))
    $total += get_field('weight');
    $count++;
    $Average = $total / $count;

  echo $Average; 
}
```

I hope somebody is able to help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a variable scope issue - inside your function, `$posts` is referring to a local variable, rather than the one you want it to. I think all you need to do is include `global $posts` at the start of the function, and that will let your function use the right variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely to be one of variable *scope*. The "scope" of a variable is the section of code where that variable "exists", if you will.

In your case, consider your foreach loop, looping through items in the '$posts' variable. Where is the $posts variable declared? I suspect that at the point of the function running, that variable doesn't exist, so the loop is not being executed at all.

I'd suggest the following amendments to your function:

```
function find_average_weight($posts)
{
    $total = 0;
    $count = 0;
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        if(get_field('weight'))
        {
            $total += get_field('weight');
            $count++;
        }
    }
    $Average = $total / $count;
    return $Average; 
}
```

There's a few changes here.

- While writing the function out I realised your foreach loop had no braces. This can cause issues of readability and indeed make the logic work incorrectly, so I put them in :)
- I added an parameter to the function to pass the required "$posts" variable in.
- I changed the function name to be slightly more descriptive, though not knowing the exact application I may be off the mark here, so take the suggestion with a grain of salt.
- I altered your function to return a value, which you can then do whatever you wish with. This makes the function a little more agnostic regarding what your intentions are - perhaps at some point you will want to find the average of these posts without outputting the results?

To use the new function and output the result, you could now write a line like this:

```
echo(find_average_weight($posts));
```

Comment: Just let me say - thank you very, very much for you patience! It works! Also the one above! Big thanks to the community!

Comment: Maybe you have some advise for a little noob again :-( - Maybe you know why this function-call echo(find_average_weight($posts)); doesn't work in a single.php of my template? The same error say hello again :-(

Comment: Without seeing your code more fully, I can't really say what's causing the error. I'd recommend you create a new question to resolve your problem.

Comment: Hello Hecksa, new question was created here. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571579/function-in-single-php-doesnt-get-correct-value-from-custom-field[/link] - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues at play here. The main one is that $posts isn't defined in the function. Turning on error checking will help notice these issues. Try adding posts to the function:

```
function averageit($posts){
```

For readability I always like to use braces after if statements and for loops. In your case it will cause an issue.

This:

```
if(get_field('weight'))
    $total += get_field('weight');
    $count++;
    $Average = $total / $count;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(get_field('weight')){
    $total += get_field('weight');
}
$count++;
$Average = $total / $count;
```

Similarly your loop if only looping the first if. Try rearranging and adding braces:

```
function averageit($posts){
    $total = 0;
    $count = 0;
    foreach($posts as $post){
        if(get_field('weight')){
            $total += get_field('weight');
            $count++;
        }
    }
    $Average = $total / $count;
    echo $Average; 
}
```

Comment: Just let me say - thank you very, very much for you patience! It works! Also the one below! Big thanks to the community!

Comment: Maybe you have some advise for a little noob again :-( - Maybe you know why this function-call  doesn't work in a single.php of my template? The same error says hello again :-( Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @user3049948 It's possibly worth asking a new question. I'd follow the code through and make sure that `$posts` is definitely available.

Comment: Hello Jim, the new question is here. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571579/function-in-single-php-doesnt-get-correct-value-from-custom-field[/link] - Thank you!