# Function in single.php doesn't get correct value from custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I guess the solution is again so stupid easy and I'm sorry in advance that I waste your time with it gain. Last week I had trouble with the same function and it didn't worked for me because I didn't set $post as a global variable. I fixed it and everything works fine for the category.php but now I want to call the same function in single.php of my wp-theme but now I have the same trouble there like the first time with the category.php that the function don't start to calc with the custom fields (ACF) correctly. Result is always 1

```
function averageit($posts){
global $post;
$total = 0;
$count = 0;
foreach($posts as $post)
{
    if(get_field('weight'))
    {
        $total += get_field('weight');
        $count++;
    }
}
$Average = $total / $count;
return $Average;
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance and have a nice weekend.

**UPDATE**

Found the solution for single.php and it was totally different to the one above... here it is:

```
$total = 0;
query_posts('category_name=' . get_option('featured-cat'));
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $total += get_post_meta($post->ID, 'weight', true);
    endwhile;
echo '<p>'.$total.'</p>';
```

Seperated the post-count in another function, there were enough possibilities to find on the net. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Is there any reason for `global $post;` besides allowing the global $post variable to be overwritten in the loop??

Comment: Hello Mark, doesn't worked for me without in a test offside wordpress. So please excuse, just a copy-error of mine through a wrong source... I'm still learning everything also a good organization. Thank you for patience.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is get_post_meta, codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Your code fixed:

```
function averageit($posts){
$total = 0;
$count = 0;
foreach($posts as $post)
{
$thisweight = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'weight', TRUE);
    if($thisweight )
    {
        $total += $thisweight;
        $count++;
    }
}
$Average = $total / $count;
return $Average;
```

General tip: store the value before checking it so you don't have to call the function again if you need it. Save clock cycles = more efficient code = conservation of energy.

Question: Why do you need to global $post before overwriting it with $posts as $post?

Another Update:  Didn't catch the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) part first read through. Their function get_field is just a wrapper for get_post_meta, so technically either will work.

Comment: Hello Jon and thank you for your quick help. Same problem. The system reacts to a change in the value of 'weight' but calculates wrong. For example. My Test have 3 posts (count) in a category, 2 have the 'weight'-value 1 and 1 have the 'weight'-value 3 (sum of this $total)... but the average result is stil 1 and not like it should be 5/3 = 1,666. That's crazy, because if I call it in category.php, your function also works like my first one but not in single.php of my Template. Excuse the $global thing copy mistake from a php file which I used testwise offside wordpress.